# Multiple values from subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to generalise my query at the bottom so I get all the projects and additional project info where my subgroup has a certain value but I can't get this to work because I can't get the [ProjectFk]

```
SELECT 
      [HeadCount].[ID],
      [LinkProjectAreaFk],
      [Month1],
      [Month2],
      [Month3],
      [Month4],
      [Month5],
      [Month6],
      [Month7],
      [Month8],
      [Month9],
      [Month10],
      [Month11],
      [Month12],
      [HcYear],
      [ApproveDirFk],
      [ApproveDirDate],
      [FreezeFk],
      [freezeDate],
      [CDSID],[FreezeTypeFk],
      [ApproveDirTypeFk],
      [SourcesFk], 
      [Project].[Title], 
      [Project].[Title]
FROM 
     [HeadCount], 
      [Project] 
WHERE 
      [HeadCount].[LinkProjectAreaFk] 
   IN 
      (SELECT 
               [ID] 
       FROM 
               [LinkProject-Area]
       WHERE
       [SubgroupFk]=1)
  and
       [Project].[ID]=[LinkProject-Area].[ProjectFk]
```

The following query works but is only for one project how can I also get the projectFk from my subquery, because when I look this up they say it's not possible and with a left outer join I can't get it to work at all

```
SELECT 
      [HeadCount].[ID],
      [LinkProjectAreaFk],
      [Month1],
      [Month2],
      [Month3],
      [Month4],
      [Month5],
      [Month6],
      [Month7],
      [Month8],
      [Month9],
      [Month10],
      [Month11],
      [Month12],
      [HcYear],
      [ApproveDirFk],
      [ApproveDirDate],
      [FreezeFk],
      [freezeDate],
      [CDSID],
      [FreezeTypeFk],
      [ApproveDirTypeFk],
      [SourcesFk], 
      [Project].[Title],
       [Project].[Title]
FROM 
      [HeadCount], 
       [Project] 
WHERE 
       [HeadCount].[LinkProjectAreaFk] IN 
      (SELECT 
            [ID] 
       FROM 
             [LinkProject-Area] 
       WHERE 
             [ProjectFk]=90 
       and 
             [SubgroupFk]=1)
        and 
             [Project].[ID]=90
```

Hope you can help me out or point me in the right direction

Kind regards

---

Hi I've been trying your way but it's still not going as it should:
I'me getting the multi-part identifier "MyCTE.ProjectFK" could not be bound. and 
 The multi-part identifier "MyCTE.ID" could not be bound. error when I look this up is has something to do with using my joins wrong any ideas?

```
     ;WITH MyCTE (ID, ProjectFK) 
    AS 
    (     
    SELECT 
           ID, 
            ProjectFk     
    FROM 
           [LinkProject-Area]     
    WHERE 
           SubgroupFk = 1 
    ) 

    SELECT 
           * 
   FROM 
             [LinkProject-Area] 
   INNER JOIN 
          HeadCount ON [LinkProjectAreaFk] = MyCTE.ID 
    INNER JOIN
           Project ON Project.ID = MyCTE.ProjectFK
```

Comment: You may get a better response if you simplify your query to the minimum needed to show the problem, format it to make it easier to read (remove the brackets unless they're needed), provide sample data and the result you expect and include your SQL Server version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to want to organize this query as something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, ProjectFk
    FROM [LinkProject-Area]
    WHERE SubgroupFk = 1
) LinkProjectAreas
INNER JOIN HeadCount ON LinkProjectAreaFK = LinkProjectAreas.ID
INNER JOIN Project ON Project.ID = LinkProjectAreas.ProjectFK
```

You could also organize this with a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
;WITH LinkProjectAreas (ID, ProjectFK) AS
(
    SELECT ID, ProjectFk
    FROM [LinkProject-Area]
    WHERE SubgroupFk = 1
)
SELECT ...
FROM LinkProjectAreas
INNER JOIN HeadCount ON LinkProjectAreaFK = LinkProjectAreas.ID
INNER JOIN Project ON Project.ID = LinkProjectAreas.ProjectFK
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, at the moment I'm trying to make your solution work but it's giving me an error on [LinkProjectAreaFk] as invalid column name or identifier could not be bound... but really thanks a lot

Comment: Hi I've been trying your way but it's still not going as it should: I'me getting the multi-part identifier "MyCTE.ProjectFK" could not be bound. and The multi-part identifier "MyCTE.ID" could not be bound. error when I look this up is has something to do with using my joins wrong any ideas?                                                              ;WITH MyCTE (ID, ProjectFK) AS ( SELECT ID, ProjectFk FROM [LinkProject-Area] WHERE SubgroupFk = 1 ) SELECT * FROM [LinkProject-Area] INNER JOIN HeadCount ON [LinkProjectAreaFk] = MyCTE.ID INNER JOIN Project ON Project.ID = MyCTE.ProjectFK

Comment: You must select the data FROM the CTE and then INNER JOIN to your other tables.

Comment: One last thank you because this learned me how to use CTE's and I have to admit this makes live easier :-D